# Is there any way to List SSO Users with their Permission Sets

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-cli

I tried to List SSO users with their permission sets from aws CLI. I couldn't find any Cli commands to list both.

I got to list Users and Permission Sets ARN sperately from below command.

List Users:
aws identitystore list-users --identity-store-id

List Permission Sets:
aws sso-admin list-permission-sets --instance-arn arn:aws:sso:::instance/<instance_id>

Is there any way to print the users and their associate permission sets

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by combining the outputs of the commands you mentioned. You can use a script or a combination of AWS CLI commands to achieve your goal. Here's a simple example using AWS CLI and jq (a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set your instance ID
INSTANCE_ID="<your-instance-id>"

# Get a list of users
USERS=$(aws identitystore list-users --identity-store-id <your-identity-store-id> | jq -r '.Users[].UserName')

# Iterate through each user and list associated permission sets
for USER in $USERS; do
    PERMISSION_SETS=$(aws sso-admin list-account-assignments --account-id <your-account-id> --instance-arn arn:aws:sso:::instance/$INSTANCE_ID --principal-type USER --principal-name $USER | jq -r '.AccountAssignments[].PermissionSetArn')
    
    echo "User: $USER"
    echo "Permission Sets:"
    echo "$PERMISSION_SETS"
    echo "------------------------"
done
```